# MYSQL trigger error 1064

Tags: mysql, triggers

I would like to check if a record is being created with a user id, if not then generate one. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
delimiter $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS init_uuid_users;

CREATE TRIGGER init_uuid_users BEFORE INSERT ON `users`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF (NEW.username IS NULL) THEN
            SET NEW.username = UUID();
        END IF;
    END;
$$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS init_uuid_users;
```

put it before delimiter.
And remove `;` after END.